# Firebase Android Auto Login

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

So I setup email/password register and login.

That is working. I thought Firebase took care of this but apparently not.
I want, after the user closes the app, to be logged in already next time they open the app.

What is missing?

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var user: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    fun loginLoginClicked(view: View) {
        // Perform login

        val email = loginEmailTxt.text.toString()
        val password = loginPasswordTxt.text.toString()

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    finish()
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.e("Exception", "Could not sign in user - ${exception.localizedMessage}")
                }
        val loginIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(loginIntent)
    }

    fun loginCreateClicked(view: View) {
        // segue to the create user activity

        val createIntent = Intent(this, SignUpActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(createIntent)
    }}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase: How to keep an Android user logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262463/firebase-how-to-keep-an-android-user-logged-in)

Answer (score 8):

Firebase Authentication does automatically remember authentication state, so the user will still be authenticated when the app is restarted.

However, if your `LoginActivity` is the launcher activity, you'll still land on this activity, so you'll need to check whether the user is authenticated in `onCreate()`, and then redirect them to your `MainActivity` if they are already logged in, something like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // User is signed in (getCurrentUser() will be null if not signed in)
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

This makes use of the [`FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) method that will return a [`FirebaseUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object if the user is logged in, or `null` if they are not logged in.

Alternatively, you could swap it around so that the `MainActivity` is the launcher activity and then only show your `LoginActivity` if the user is not logged in.

....

Comment: How can I make sure the user is logged in?

Comment: Because I deleted all the users, and the code you gave me still takes me to the MainActivity. And there are no users so it is impossible to be logged in

Comment: Like I've shown in my example: `auth.getCurrentUser()` will be `null` if the user is not logged in. If the user is logged in, the `auth.getCurrentUser()` will return a `FirebaseUser` object.

Comment: No, you will still be logged in - [even if the user is deleted, your app will still hold an authentication token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961217/2754146), so is technically still authenticated. To logout, clear the app data or use [`FirebaseAuth#signOut()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signOut()).

Comment: You can clear app data on the Android device through: `Settings > Applications > Your App > Clear Data`, or use [`adb shell pm clear packageName`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934304/clear-android-application-user-data) where `packageName` is the full package name of your app.

Comment: Anyway apart from signet or that to check/incheck that token?

Comment: The only way to clear the authentication session (and logout the current user) is to clear the app data or call [`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signOut()).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone landing up here for achieving same thing using Java then use following code (credit to [Grimthorr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47286015) for the Kotlin version that this is a port of)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // User is signed in (getCurrentUser() will be null if not signed in)
        Intent intent = Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        // or do some other stuff that you want to do
    }
```